# Clock sync for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, time, clock

I'm using a Windows Phone 7.5. 
Is there a way to automatically sync the current time with some internet time server? 
I'm really surprised about the fact that I need to enter the time manually. Even more, my clock was shifting about 3 minutes in 4 weeks.
Kind regards Georg

Answer (score 1):

Automatic time is work only if your mobile operator provide this service, it's not SNTP sync.

You can only check time is actual with [Internet Time](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/92977e5d-5c5d-445b-96f1-e3d857616023) app

However no such possibility to change system time from application, so no such app, that can automatically sync time from internet.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings => date+time and make sure that 'Set automatically' is set to on

This should sync the clock to an internet server

Comment: For some reason there are a few phones that don't show that setting, including my HTC Trophy 7 (with the latest 8107 build) on Vodafone UK.

Comment: i also don't see the option on a Nokia Lumia 800, Vigin Mobile Australia, OS 7.10.8107.79